# Not CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there some kind of "not" CSS selector?

For example when I write the following line in my CSS, all input fields inside an tag with class *classname* will have a red background.

```css
.classname input {
  background: red;
}
```

How do I select all input fields that are OUTSIDE of a tag with class *classname*?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

<del>**With current browser CSS support, you can't.**</del>

*Newer browsers now support it- see [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726493/negative-css-selectors#6294916) for more info.*

(See other answers for the alternatives in CSS.)

If doing it in JavaScript/jQuery is acceptable, you can do:

```
$j(':not(.classname)>input').css({background:'red'});
```

Comment: Wouldn't the selector be "*:not(.classname) input"?

Comment: Ah, misread the question. Yes, it should - although the * is optional.

Comment: Ah, also, need to use direct descendant (a>b) rather than any descendant (a b) otherwise all inputs will match since there is likely to be a higher container without the class (like body).

Comment: You can do this with CSS in current browsers now -- see answer below.

Comment: Down-voted; if you can do it in jQuery you SHOULD do it in pure JavaScript *without* dumping 70KB worth of extra bandwidth that has to be handled.

Answer (score 32):

Mozilla supports [negation pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

```
:not(.classname) input {background: red;}
```

See also: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_CSS_support_chart

Comment: ie9+ support this too.

Comment: also chrome, safari, and opera, scroll down and read more answers if you dont believe me ;P

Comment: Oh, I believe you. I just never bothered to come back and expand on my answer that I provided exactly 6 years and 1 week ago. :D

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to add to your answer.... I wanted to add styles to all a tags which were descendants of my header, except for an a tag with class (.no_in_cart) so with your solution I tried: #headernav li :not(.no_in_cart) a{background: red;} which did not work so I tried this #headernav li a:not(.no_in_cart){background: red;} which did work.

Answer (score 31):

Note that the negation pseudo class is in the [Selectors Level 3 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors) and works in recent versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari (at least). Sample code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Negation pseudo class</title>
<style type="text/css">
    div {
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 10px;
    }
    div:not(#foo) {
    border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="foobar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Now supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) in released versions of all major browsers. ([Automated test](http://www.css3.info/selectors-test/) available if you want to double-check that `:not()` is supported.)

Comment: Perhaps also worth adding that you can chain them together:

`div:not(#foo):not(#bar)`

Comment: FWIW I've put a simple negative selector demo at http://simpl.info/cssnegativeselector.

Answer (score 24):

Wouldn't you do that by setting the 'global' background to red, then using the classname to alter the others?

```
input { background: red; }
.classname input { background: white; }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I try to find a workaround for because it's not just the background that is changed...

Comment: Override each of the options in the `.classname input` rule.

Comment: you try ".classname input { background-color: white ! important; }" ??

Answer (score 10):

I would do this

```
input { /* styles outside of .classname */ }
.classname input { /* styles inside of .classname, overriding above */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to select the parent of matched elements with CSS. You would have to use JavaScript to select them.

From your question I assume you have markup that looks more or less like this:

```
<form class="formclassname">
    <div class="classname">
        <input />  <!-- Your rule matches this -->
        <input />  <!-- Your rule matches this -->
    </div>
    <input />  <!-- You want to select this? -->
    <input />  <!-- You want to select this? -->
</form>
```

One option is to add a class to a higher element, say the `<form>`, and write a rule to style all of the inputs of the form. I.E:

```
.formclassname input {
  /* Some properties here... */
}
```

Or

```
.formclassname > input {
  /* Some properties here... */
}
```

If you want to select them based on the fact that they are not inside of an element with a specific class, you're out of luck without the use of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get is to only affect direct descendants with a declaration

This code for example will only affect input fields directly under divs with class "maincontent"

```
div.maincontent > input {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inputs are a bit annoying because, unlike most other html elements, there isn't necessarily a way of resetting all the css properties back to their default value.

If the styling is non-critical (ie a nice to have but doesn't affect functionality) I would use jQuery to get an array of all the inputs, check their parents, and then only carry out the styling on those outside that div. Something like:

```
$('input').each(function() {
     if($(this).closest('.classname') == false)
     {
           // apply css styles
     }
});
```

(By the way, I'm no jQuery expert, so there might be some errors in the above, but in principle something like this should work)