# Separate CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Negative CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726493/negative-css-selectors)

I would like to separate some CSS on my page,
i have a div

```
<div class="separate">
    <a href="#">a link</a>
</div>
```

so that when I say

```
div{
    background:red;
}
```

all divs except .separate turn red
i need a way to do this without iframes

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using CSS3's `not` selector, and will work in all browsers **except** internet explorer (surprise surprise):

```
div:not(#seperate){
     background:red;
}
```

As described here: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/

As for IE, I don't think this can be done (unless you give every div (except seperate) another class that does this.

For example

```
<div class="origClass notSeperate"></div>
<div class="seperate></div>
<div class="origClass2 notSeperate"></div>
```

But that's silly :)

Comment: Actually good idea, but wrong selector :) You should write `.seperate`, not `#seperate`.

Answer (score 1):

just add any style you want to separate but do it after

```
div{
       background:red;
   }
```

for example:

```
.separate{
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: quite messy solution, when it comes to modifying only div's. Why not `div.separate` instead of `.separate`?

Comment: `div.separate` is useless if the separate-class was set on div's only. `.separate` is sufficient, because CSS selectors are parsed from right to left. So the client searches for all occurrences of `.separate` and after that searches again for all div's and then returning only the ones with the specified class. That would decrease CSS-parsing time. And styling all div's first, then styling the exceptions was the common practise until CSS3, which still isn't fully supported by browsers. This is described in @Guffa's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background for all divs, then override it with no background for the specific class:

```
div { background-color: red; }
div.separate { background-color: transparent; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:

1. Specifying different background color for `div.separate` divs (that way it will not be overwritten) - [see proof in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSd3M/).
2. Using `div:not(.separate)` selector, but it will be supported only in browsers supporting CSS3 ([see more](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation)) - [see proof in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSd3M/1/).
3. Use JavaScript (eg. jQuery framework) and set it using CSS3 selectors (that way it will work in all major browsers) - [see proof in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSd3M/2/).

But I suggest solution no. 1, as it is cross-browser and does not require JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Negative CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726493/negative-css-selectors)

You can do it with the help from javascript (example with jquery):

`$j('.not(.separate)>div').css({background:'red'});`

OR

You can do something like this:

```
div { background: red; }
.separate { background: white; }
```

OR

The you can add an appropriate style class to the divs you want to be red.