# CSS selector, is no descendant of

Tags: css, css-selectors

How would i select images in this document that are not inside a element with a .todeep class? In the case below the second and the third element should be selected.
I don't know how deep the images will be after a "todeep" element.

```
<body>
   <div class="todeep">
       <img>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img>
       <div>
           <img>
           <div class="todeep">
               <img>
               <div>
                   <img />
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I first thought of a simple solution: *:not(.todeep) img, but this will also select images that have a non "todeep" element among their ancestors also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Negative CSS selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726493/negative-css-selectors)

Answer (score 7):

You will have to select all images, and then negate the ones which have a `.todeep` parent.

So instead of

```
img { background-color: blue; width: 20px; height: 20px; }
*:not(.todeep) img { background-color: red; }
```

use

```
img { background-color: red; width: 20px; height: 20px; }
.todeep img { background-color: blue; }
```

(example code borrowed from You's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTT9k/))

Comment: That's for `img` children only, not descendants at any level. Replace the child selector with the descendant selector.