# D3.js : Select the NOT selected to fade them (line chart, line chart legend)

Tags: d3.js

In a multi line chart I successfully highlight a line when I mouseover, as well as make the corresponding entry in a legend appear bold and larger. I also want to fade the other names in the legend to further increase contrast.  How do I make a selection of the names NOT in my selection for the mouseover?

Here is an excerpt of my mouseover event:

```
.on("mouseover", function (d) {                                  
   d3.select(this)                  
      .style("stroke-width",'6px'); // Make the line thicker on mouseover.
   var getname = document.getElementById(d.name);  // Line name to highlight in legend

// How to get the list of names NOT selected??
//var notsel = ??? (not(getname) ??  
    d3.selectAll(notsel)  // Fade the non-selected names in the legend
      .style("opacity",.2);

//This class highlights the selected name by CSS (not shown)
d3.select(getname)
  .attr("class", "legend-select");  //Change class to highlight name
```

Answer (score 1):

D3 uses css3 selectors, so what you're looking for is a negative css selector.  Turns out those exist.  [Negative CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726493/negative-css-selectors)

Try something like this

```
d3.selectAll(':not('+getname+')')  // Fade the non-selected names in the legend
  .style("opacity",.2);
```