# How to add a class to all images except specific ones with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a Class to all images except for two specific ones. Because i don't want to add that Class to the logo for example.

This is what i have now:

```
$('img').addClass('class_two');
```

The images where i don't want to add this class on are:

```
<img id="id_1" src="danielgotzlogo.png" alt="danielgotzlogo">
<img id="id_2" src="xxsbanner.jpg" alt="#">
```

But this adds it to all images. How can i not add the Class to specific ones?

Comment: Do you mean a class? I ask as `id` attributes must be unique. You cannot apply the same one to multiple elements. Also, what is the rules for identifying the images you *do not* want to put the class on?

Comment: Define your *specific ones* and filter them.

Comment: use if statement and check for a specific rule true only for those exceptions

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah i ment a class.

Comment: What Rory said - you haven't said how you identify the two images that _won't_ get the new class.    Also, please edit your question to clarify that it is indeed a class you want to add, not an ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726493/negative-css-selectors)

Comment: @Alnitak i'll identify them by id="id_1" and id="id_2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the specific IDs of the two elements you don't want to affect:

```
$('img').not('#id1').not('#id2').addClass('myclass');
```

or:

```
$('img').not('#id1,#id2').addClass('myclass');
```

or:

```
$('img:not(#id1,#id2)').addClass('myclass');
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good point, although I wonder what the relative efficiency would be

Comment: It still adds the class to the images.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`$("img:not(#id_1,#id_2)").addClass("class_two");`

If your logo (on which you do not want to add the class) has the class `logo` then try then you can try the following also:

`$("img:not(.logo)").addClass("class_two");`

Comment: Note that OP has edited the question as they meant classes, not ids

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function like this:

```
function _addClass(klass, to, except){
    $(to).not(except.join()).addClass(klass)
}

_addClass('class_two', 'img', ['#id_1', '#id_1'])
```

This will add the class 'klass' to every elements 'to' except those matching the 'except' selector.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/89314/