# How can we prevent a specific element from inheriting CSS rules with * sign?

Tags: css

I have defined this CSS rule:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

What if we want to exclude only a specific element with this class `.testim`?

Comment: You can use :not(.testim) as a modifier on the *

Comment: How... Show us please..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726493/not-css-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple; If I correct undertood then;

```
.testim,
.testim::before,
.testim::after{
  box-sizing: unset;
}
```

*The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if the property naturally inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not.*

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) for CSS `unset` value.

Comment: Be sure to install it after your reset codes and you might want to try `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

`:not()` is like `*`. It selects every element apart from the element in its brackets. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

```css
:not(.testim), *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  border: 20px solid black;
}

.testim {
  width: 200px;
  border: 20px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>I am div with width: 200px and border: 20px.</div>
<hr>
<div class="testim">I am of the class testim with width: 200px and border: 20px.</div>
```